# Accessing wordpress through the internet, on windows server 2012?

Tags: wordpress, windows-server-2012-r2, iis-8.5

I've installed wordpress on windows server 2012, using web platform installer 5.
the site works quite well on localhost, but my problem is that while trying to connect the site through the internet, none of CSSs and other contents load. I just see some text and html links, which does'nt work properly. My sites appearance is as bellow:

```
http://46.4.122.114:8080/wordpress/
```

Comment: You should probably consider asking your web host.

Comment: @rnevius: This is a dedicated server, of which, I'm using for serving some other sites. What problem would probably exist by the server?
I guess it relates to IIS.

Answer (score 0):

If you view your page source, all of your links are pointing to your localhost still. You'll need to update these in your database ([see moving WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress) for more info).

Obviously, you'll also have to update any hard-coded URLs that reference `http://localhost:8080/` to point to the correct site URL.

Comment: I updated to wordpress V.4, after installing version 3 by web platform installer. Is it possible that the update, has made the links broken?